# Does SciChart works on Windows Phones with Windows 10?

Tags: scichart

I'm working on a project where I need charts on iOS, Android an WP to look the same. I was hoping to use SciChart, but I'm not sure if it will work on Windows Phones with Windows 10.

Did anyone try that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of October 2017 [SciChart](https://www.scichart.com) supports the following platforms:

- WPF (Windows Presentation Foundation) on Windows Vista, 7, 8, 10
- iOS 7+ (Swift, OBjective C)
- Xamarin.iOS
- Android v4.4.4 Kitkat+
- Xamarin.Android

At the moment (Oct 2017) SciChart does not support Universal Windows Platform which is required for Windows Phone but there [is a prototype in progress now](https://www.scichart.com/coming-soon-scichart-q3q4-2017/).

*Disclosure, I am the tech lead of the SciChart project*